# Use standard js object properties on objects returned by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just getting into jQuery so please forgive this maby stupid question, but I encountert the following:

```
$('#pb_inner').css('width',data + '%');
```

this code works fine. However I wonder why I can't do the following?

```
$('#pb_inner').style.width=data + '%';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$('#pb_inner')` returns an array like jQuery object. A collection, not a single object (and even then, it would be another jQuery object):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> (...), `jQuery()` — which can also be written as `$()` — searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements.

---

You would have to use [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$('#pb_inner').get(0).style.width=data + '%';
```

> The `.get()` method grants us access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object

Answer (score 1):

Because `$('#pb_inner')` returns a jQuery object not the raw DOMElement. You could use the properties if you retrieve the actual DOMElement from that jQuery object, for example:

```
$('#pb_inner').get(0).style.width=data + '%';
```

Answer (score 1):

the selector `$('#pb_inner')` returns an array of jQuery wrapped objects matching the given parameter string.

the following will work

`$('#pb_inner').get(0).style.width=data + '%'`

`get(0)` will return the first object from the jQuery array, as a native DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

And btw there is an advantage with using jQuery .css() method since you can write multiple CSS rules in it by passing an object, like in example:

```
$('#pb_inner').css({
  'width': data + '%',
  'height': data + '%',
  'color': '#eaeaea'
})
```